# Avoid duplicate while generate list of items from a set of patterns

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to create a item list with specific patterns, so far my design is like this,

```
patterns = [
   '{column1}{column2}',
   '{column1}@{column3}',
   '{column2}#{column4}',
   '{column3}!@#'
]

for c1 in possible_column1:
   for c2 in possible_column2:
     for c3 in possible_column3:
        for c4 in possible_column4:
          data = { 
             'column1': c1,
             'column2': c2,
             'column3': c3,
             'column4': c4,
          }
          for pattern in patterns:
              result.append(pattern.format(**data))
```

The design has many problems,

1. It create duplicate values, and I have to do a `list(set(result))` to unique the list
2. It's slow

What's the common way of writing such algorithms?

The `patterns` list varies and will be changed frequently, new type of columns maybe added as well

P.S
*In my opinion, this differs from permutations.*

Comment: @xenteros it's not a permutation, it's a fixed pattern

Comment: @daisy If it is not a permutation, I do not understand your question.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis updated the pattern

Comment: You can use `itertools.product()` instead of the 4 nested loops. I agree that it is not a permutation, it is a cartesian product.

Comment: The fact that the pattern is *funky* does not make it **not** a permutation

Comment: I wanna see if I understand, you want to always get the values that are inside `{}` no matter the separator? If that's what you're looking for it can be done with regex (`re` package), and then you can still `list(set(result))` at the end to get unique values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use another data structure (a `dict`) to keep the patterns:

```
patterns = {
   '{0}{1}':  (possible_column1, possible_column2),
   '{0}@{1}': (possible_column1, possible_column3),
   '{0}#{1}': (possible_column2, possible_column4),
   '{0}!@#':  (possible_column3, )
}
```

With that dictionary you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) on the "values" of that dictionary:

```
from itertools import product

# Just some data for the possible columns...
possible_column1 = list('12')
possible_column2 = list('34')
possible_column3 = list('56')
possible_column4 = list('78')

result = []
for pattern, cols in patterns.items():
    for prod in product(*cols):
        result.append(pattern.format(*prod))

# or if you like it shorter:
# result = [pattern.format(*prod) for pattern, cols in patterns.items() for prod in product(*cols)]
```

That way you don't create the duplicated entries.